# Two classes inheriting from the same base to see each other

Tags: c++, inheritance, visibility

I have a program with a lot of classes. I want classes in the program to be visible to each other. For that, I am following a trick such that all classes are inherited from a base class, which holds pointers to every class. But I hit an error in doing so. Below is a piece of code produces the error I am after:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AClass;
class BClass;

class RoofClass {
 public:  
  RoofClass();
  AClass* a_class;
  BClass* b_class;
};

class BaseClass {
 public:  
  BaseClass(RoofClass* roof_class) {
   a_class = roof_class->a_class;
   b_class = roof_class->b_class;
  }
  AClass* a_class;
  BClass* b_class;  
};

class AClass : public BaseClass {
 public:  
  AClass(RoofClass* roof_class) : BaseClass(roof_class) {}
  void Afunction();
  int Aint = 1;
};

class BClass : public BaseClass {
 public:  
  BClass(RoofClass* roof_class) : BaseClass(roof_class) {}
  void Bfunction();
  int Bint = 2;
};

void AClass::Afunction() {
  cout << b_class->Bint << endl;
}

void BClass::Bfunction() {
  cout << a_class->Aint << endl;
}

RoofClass::RoofClass() {
  a_class = new AClass(this);
  b_class = new BClass(this);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  RoofClass roof_class;  
  cout << "b calls a" << endl;
  roof_class.b_class->Bfunction();
  cout << "a calls b" << endl;
  roof_class.a_class->Afunction();
}
```

Roof is the top level class which consists of classes A and B. I want A and B visible to each other. To achieve that, as I said, they both inherit from the Base class. My problem, in particular, is that while B sees A, A does not see B. The reason for this is probably due to the fact that A is initialized before B in constructor of Roof. So, why can I solve this issue?

Comment: Whenever you have a pointer to an instance of another object like this, you are just *asking* to have a dangling reference if one of them gets `delete`d.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. The `RoofClass` constructor first creates an instance of `AClass`, passing a pointer to itself with uninitialized members `a_class` and `b_class`. Then, `AClass` constructor copies those uninitialized members. Then it returns, and `RoofClass` constructor sets `a_class` to point to the newly created object, and repeats the same with class B.

Comment: @riv At the end, I just want A and B to see each other. I actually want them to see the RoofClass as well but did not include that part for simplicity.

Comment: @emre Are you asking for something like [`std::ahared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) collections actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am just not very familiar with them. But if it is the solution, I am willing to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the question. It is like this:
In its constructor, the RoofClass creates a and b objects, in order. It first initializes a object by going into its constructor (which actually is the constructor of BaseClass due to inheritance) and setting a's a and b objects to roof's a and b. But the problem is that, roof's b is not constructed yet. That is why, a's b is initialized to a value of 00000000. When the RoofClass goes to b object's constructor for initialization, this time both roof's a and b are in place so that b's a and b's b are properly initialized. That is why, b can have a proper a but not vice versa.

The solution is introducing an InitPointer function to the base class, which acts after the roof objects constructs all a and b objects. This way, InitPointer sets pointers of a and b objects to already constructed a and b objects. Here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class AClass;
class BClass;

class RoofClass {
 public:  
  RoofClass();
  AClass* a_class;
  BClass* b_class;
};

class BaseClass {
 public:  
  BaseClass() {}
  void InitPointer(RoofClass* roof_class) {
    a_class = roof_class->a_class;
    b_class = roof_class->b_class;
  }
  AClass* a_class;
  BClass* b_class;  
};

class AClass : public BaseClass {
 public:  
  AClass() : BaseClass() {}
  void Afunction();
  int Aint = 1;
};

class BClass : public BaseClass {
 public:  
  BClass() : BaseClass() {}
  void Bfunction();
  int Bint = 2;
};

void AClass::Afunction() {
  cout << b_class->Bint << endl;
}

void BClass::Bfunction() {
  cout << a_class->Aint << endl;
}

RoofClass::RoofClass() {
  a_class = new AClass();
  b_class = new BClass();
  a_class->InitPointer(this);
  b_class->InitPointer(this);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  RoofClass roof_class;  
  cout << "b calls a" << endl;
  roof_class.b_class->Bfunction();
  cout << "a calls b" << endl;
  roof_class.a_class->Afunction();
}
```

Thanks for the all discussion!

Answer (score 1):

When `RoofClass` constructor creates an instance of `AClass`, it passes a pointer to itself, with uninitialized members `a_class` and `b_class`. `AClass` constructor then copies those values and returns. When `RoofClass` constructor sets `a_class` to point to the newly constructed object, the pointers inside `AClass` are still pointing to nothing.

You probably want `BaseClass` to store a pointer to `RoofClass` instead:

```
class BaseClass {
 public:  
  BaseClass(RoofClass* roof_class) {
   r_class = roof_class;
  }
  RoofClass* r_class;
};
class AClass : public BaseClass {
 public:  
  AClass(RoofClass* roof_class) : BaseClass(roof_class) {}
  void Afunction();
  int Aint = 1;
  // access class B as r_class->b_class
};
```

Comment: riv, I know that there is a solution to this error the way I want it, that is: B accessing A as a_class not as roof_class->a_class. So, I will keep looking for it.